# UITableView weirdness! with pictures

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UIViewController that allows me to view and edit information of a class.

It is only allocated once but it's number of rows,sections and data is passed to it depending on the value the user selected.

For example. Here it is editing a name & type property (Header view of table is too big.. I did this so you will see the weirdness underneath)

[image]

So I enter a name and it all displays fine. Then I click on the address property and the detail view now looks like this:

[image]

Everything Ok so far. If i click cancel and go back to edit the name property it displays fine. 
The problem is this. I scroll down the address table like so:

[image]

And then click save/cancel. Now when I go back to edit the name property, the tableview looks like this!

[image]

It's as though the previous table is still visible through the header view of the table..?

My viewWillAppear: method for this uiviewcontroller looks like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

NSLog(@"Retain count of poolcopy is %d\n\n", [self.thePoolFacilityCopy retainCount] );
//This will be a reference to find our which pool Instance field we are editing.
self.sectionFromParentTable = self.cellPath.section;
//This will only be used by the arrays
self.rowFromPreviousTable = self.cellPath.row;

NSString *sectionName;  

switch (self.sectionFromParentTable) {
    case KNameIndex:
        sectionName = @"name";

        break;
    case KAddressIndex:
        sectionName = @"address";

        break;
    case KPhoneNumberIndex:
        sectionName = @"phone";

        break;
    case KWebAddressIndex:
        sectionName = @"url";

        break;
    case KPricesIndex:
        sectionName = @"prices";

        break;
    case KPoolIndex:
        sectionName = @"pools";

    default:
        break;
}



self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Editing %@", sectionName];

// use an empty view to position the cells in the vertical center of the portion of the view not covered by 
// the keyboard


if (self.sectionFromParentTable == KPhoneNumberIndex || self.sectionFromParentTable == KWebAddressIndex) {

    UIView *singleSectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 60)];
    self.theTableView.tableHeaderView = singleSectionHeaderView;
    [singleSectionHeaderView release];

    self.theTableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 10)]autorelease];

}
else if (self.sectionFromParentTable == KAddressIndex) {
    UIView *addressHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 0)];
    self.theTableView.tableHeaderView = addressHeaderView;
    [addressHeaderView release];

    self.theTableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 250)]autorelease];
}
else if (self.sectionFromParentTable == KPoolIndex) {
    UIView *poolHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 2)];
    self.theTableView.tableHeaderView = poolHeaderView;
    [poolHeaderView release];

    self.theTableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 10)]autorelease];

}
else {
    UIView *doubleSectionHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 30)];
    self.theTableView.tableHeaderView = doubleSectionHeaderView;
    [doubleSectionHeaderView release];

    self.theTableView.tableFooterView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 10)]autorelease];
}



[self.theTableView reloadData];
```

}

In the picture where the table looks messed up the cellForRowAtIndexPath method is only being called twice, even though there are 3 cells visible (2 normal cells and one weird cell). The weird cell moves with the scroll and is still clickable.

I can fix this problem by commenting out the following lines in this method. However I don't want to have to allocate a new controller everytime someone wants to edit a detail:

```
    - (PoolFacilityDetailEditController *)childController {
    // Instantiate the editing view controller if necessary.
   // if (childController == nil) {
        PoolFacilityDetailEditController *controller = [[PoolFacilityDetailEditController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PoolFacilityDetailEditController" bundle:nil];
        self.childController = controller;
        [controller release];
  // }
    return childController;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell without looking at all the code, but is it possible that you're not recycling your tableview cells properly? You have to assign a different reuseIdentifier for each cell that's rendered differently. If a header cell is getting reused as a detail cell (or vice-versa) that'll cause some oddities in rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Do use another class by TableViewCell, completely customize it as per your requirement. Then do import that into your code. It works!!